# issue with multiplying a define by a negative number

Tags: c

I want to understand the basics of this issue.
I suspect that something is wrong with the casting, it is occasionally entering the if statement when it is not supposed to. i read some posts but couldn't understand what is the issue exactly.
relevant code:

```
int32_t my_int_var;  // this should not be less than -20
#define MY_DEFAULT_VAR 20u
if(my_int_var < (-1*MY_DEFAULT_VAR)){
FailTest();
}
```

Comment: `#define MY_DEFAULT_VAR` is empty so the preprocessor replaces every occurence of `MY_DEFAULT_VAR` with nothing. That results in a syntax error `(-1*)`

Comment: please see fixed snippet

Comment: `20u` mean unsigned, you are multiplying unsigned by `-1` which makes no sense

Comment: What do you mean by "failing"? Does it not compile, or crash, or produce strange values, or send LinkedIn invitations to spammers, or what?

Comment: There is no casting in that code, so that can't possibly be a problem.

Comment: Btw you my_int_var not initialized, so what you expect to compare?

Comment: Make sure you understand the [C11 Standard - 6.3.1.1 Boolean, characters, and integers(p2) (Integer Promotion Rules)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.1p2)

Comment: SO post about the topic: [Implicit type promotion rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46073295/implicit-type-promotion-rules)

Answer (score 4):

Because of the '*u*' at the end of MY_DEFAULT_VAR value, there is an implicit conversion from signed to unsigned by the expression

```
-1 * MY_DEFAULT_VAR
```

This results in an unsigned number so

the comparison is a large  unsigned number `0xffffffe0`

This now doesn't behave as expected e.g. if my_int_var was 20

```
if( 20 < 0xffffffe0 ) { /* this would now be true */
```

Comment: thansk , can you please explain why This results in an unsigned number